# Tracking of an added object in the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database. The user can do:

- add item to the database
- update item in the database

I have a function that tracks the database in a specific position. At the moment I have one function for new items and for updated items

This function will be called when there is something new and when there is an update of an existing object:

```
const readyForData = async () => {
    const ref = database().ref('users/' + user.id + '/data');
    ref.on('child_added', snapshot => {
        const ref = database().ref('/data/' + snapshot.key);
        ref.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.val()) {
                let data = snapshot.val() ? snapshot.val() : {};
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Should I do two separate `on()` functions?

- for new items
- for object update

**EDIT:**

As above, I have a function that responds when we add a new object in the database or change an existing object.

How to rebuild it to make it work more efficiently? Can separate support for new and updated objects?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your goal is here, but having an on() nested inside another on(), especially given that neither listener is ever removed, sounds like a really bad idea, as those listeners will leak and possibly pull down much more data than you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I think this too is badly done and I'm looking for how to improve it

Comment: I think it would help if you edit the question to describe more clearly what your goal is here.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) you should be able to track your data collection changes using onSnapshot function (adding or editing)